# Which team has my football?

Tags: word-property

Which of these two teams is the right place for **football**?

| team A | team B |
| --- | --- |
| birdsong | birdseed |
| butthead | butthole |
| handoff | handset |
| handover | handshake |
| outfall | outburst |
| outwith | outhouse |
| overspill | overdue |
| overturn | overtone |
| workhouse | workload |
| workpiece | workstation |

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The right place for Football is

> Team B.

Because

> All of the words in both team a and team b are compound words (as well as football), but all of the words in team A, when the two words that make up the compound word are reversed, they make up another compound word.

Examples:

> Butthead --> Headbutt/Birdsong--> songbird

And for set B:

> Birdseed cannot become seedbird. Similarly, the others, like workload cannot be reversed as well.

So,

> Football is in team B because there is no such thing as a 'ballfoot.'

Edit Dec. 2022:

> Apparantly 'seedbird' is a word according to Merriam-Webster... [Seedbird Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seedbird) Who would've thought? :)

Comment: Exactly right - well done!

Comment: *This is the Poo and Ee **Seed Bird** Company. Good ladies, evening and gentlemen.*

Comment: @iBug ...it is still two words though...